# In python design a function named addSub that will receive three parameters, numbers x,y,z and will return x y-z

Tags: python

In python, design a function named addSub that will receive three parameters, numbers x,y,z and will return x+y-z

Comment: is this homework or something?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Seems straightforward to me.  What's your question about it?

Comment: `addSub = lambda x,y,z: (x*y)-((x-1)*y)+math.sqrt(sum(x for x in xrange(x)))-z`

Answer (score 2):

```
addSub = lambda x, y, z: x+y-z
```